# Enqueueing jQuery in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, function

I am trying to enqueue my jQuery file via functions.php but it does not seem to be working.

I Know the Script works because if I put it at the bottom of the .php file enclosed in `<script>...</script>` it works fine

The file has been called jargon.js

I have called the file in functions.php using:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','asap_scripts');
// Register your assets during `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook inside 
`functions.php`.
function asap_scripts() {
   // Give the path of the script
    wp_register_script('js-jargon', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
'/js/jargon.js',array('jquery')); 
}
```

I am using jQuery and my JS code is the following :

```
function toggleAnswer() { 
jQuery(this).next('.jargon-desc').slideToggle();
 } 

 jQuery('.jargon-desc').hide();

 jQuery('.jargon-header').click(toggleAnswer);
```

Any help would be great.
I have called other scripts using the same method and worked great. but I seem to be having issues with this one..?

Comment: Give a person a fish, they eat for a day, teach a person to fish, they eat for life: What is the path that is "Regitistered" when you run your code? When you "View Source" in your browser, what's the full path? If you click on the full path, what loads? Are you confident your action is firing? What have you done to test / ensure it is firing? For example, if you put `var_dump(get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` inside the `asap_scripts` function, what does it output?

Comment: @cale_b - `wp_register_script()` is a built-in wp function for including styles / scripts in the header or footer based on some hooks. it is very standard output on html `<script>` tag based on inputted parameters. very standard procedure in wordpress.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen - indeed, it is. Not sure what I said that gave you the impression that I thought that was part of the problem.  What I think the problem is relates to _the path_ of where OP's script files are....

Comment: @cale_b - sorry, my bad. I just saw the `var_dump()` and assumed that you regard the `register_script()`  as a `normal` function written by OP or something like that . Sorry for that . Should have read through the parameters. :-)  Anyhow the problem seems to be that OP is not even enqueuing .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - please include the JS in the question, and the error you get from console or php, log etc  ( `not working` is not a description .. )

ANYHOW --

As it seems you are **registering** the script handle but not really **enqeuing** it ..

```
     <?php
    function asap_scripts() {

    wp_register_script('my_amazing_script_handle',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
'/js/jargon.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);

    wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script_handle');
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'asap_scripts' );  
    ?>
```

As you can see, `wp_register_script()` only registers your handle, and then `wp_enqueue_script()` is the one actually firing the inclusion based on the registered handle..

As for the other possible culprits and as a rule of thumb for debugging ( for lack of info in OP )  :

Try the three following points combined for debugging :

- Specify jQuery instead of $. ( known issue in wp )

if you use jQuery - then specify `jQuery('el')` and not `$('el')`

- Enqueue the scripts at the footer ( hooking wp_footer() action )

Like so :

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-handler-js', 
                    plugins_url( '/src/my-script.js', dirname( __FILE__ ) ), 
                    array( 'jquery' ), 
                    filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/src/my-script.js' ), 
    ,'ver', TRUE );
```

- firing with `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { ... });`

Comment: JS - `function toggleAnswer() {
    jQuery(this).next('.jargon-desc').slideToggle();
  }
  
  jQuery('.jargon-desc').hide();
  
  jQuery('.jargon-header').click(toggleAnswer);`

Comment: @SupGen - please add it to your question ( edit ) along with some debug info ( console errors ? ) - also see my answer regarding `wp_enqueue_script`  VS `wp_register_script`

Answer (score 0):

@ObmerkKronen thank you for your help.

I made a simple change to:

`function ASAP_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('js-jargon', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jargon.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('js-jargon');
    }

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ASAP_scripts' );  `
```

Worked perfect.  thanks again

Comment: Good. now regarding this answer -  first you can comment on my answer instead of adding another answer :-)  . and second, if my answer resolved your issue try [to accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) ( clicking on the little green icon near the score ) in order to mark it as resolved ..